# Redirect multiple urls to single URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, seo

i'm doing some work on a legacy asp.net and umbraco site. It's using UrlRewritingNet to set up rules for url manipulation.

I'd like to create a rule in the UrlRewritingNet file to redirect multiple urls to a single URL. This is for SEO purposes to reference a page to prevent dilution of page relevance.

Hence i'd like http://www.test.com/index.aspx and http://www.test.com/index to redirect to http://www.test.com.

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<add name="Rule1" ignoreCase="true" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
  redirectMode="Permanent"
  redirect="Application"
  virtualUrl="~/index(.*)"
  destinationUrl="^~/$"/>
```

Can you please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this as I don't have an environment, but try destinationUrl="~/", the ^ and $ are regex start and end of string characters that you shouldn't need.

Comment: yes, the correct answer is:                                <add name="Rule1" ignoreCase="true" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
  redirectMode="Permanent"
  redirect="Application"
  virtualUrl="~/index(.*)"
  destinationUrl="~/"/>